# How to resolve ambiguous error in the query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, join, laravel-query-builder

I am using laravel framework for developing API's ,i have one query that is executed without where condition without any error i need to execute with where condition but it's throwing an error

`query`

```
select count(*) as aggregate
from `users`
  left join `books` on `books`.`book_id` = `books`.`id`
where `access_id` = 5054
```

> SQL Error [1052] [23000]: Column 'access_id' in where clause is
> ambiguous

after searching google i got something we have to specify reference of a table name , i added reference name like this **where `users.access_id` =5054** but it's throwing an error like unknown column but in my db i have that column in both users and books table

Comment: Qualify it with a table name (or alias). This is basically saying you have this column name in more than one table of this query

Comment: This line may need you to have a second think!!  `left join \`books\` on \`books\`.\`book_id\` = \`books\`.\`id\`` You really need something about `user` in there

Comment: Nothing in there looks specifically like `Laravel` or `Query Builder`

Comment: @RiggsFolly, that join query is automatically generated by repository pattern so that's why i need that line

Comment: Maybe you should show us the code that creates this query

Comment: Start an SQL question by showing the schema for all the relevant tables. Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` for each table, and paste it into the questions as text (NOT A PICTURE). 
An example of the data contained in these tables is also very useful. 
If at all possible create a SQLFiddle with the schema defined and some test data provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is its consider as a column so that's why syntax error is coming,try following way it will resolve your problem

```
select count(*) as aggregate
from `users`
  left join `books` on `books`.`book_id` = `books`.`id`
where `users`.`access_id` = 5054
```